# aquaris e4.5 as hotspot

Tags: wireless-access-point

I've had my phone Aquaris E4.5 for a week now and find that it works really well.

I miss however the possibility of using it as HOTSPOT.
Whether it's WiFi or USB does not matter.
I should be able to use it on both a window 7 and 8 and a Ubuntu PC.
I have found some TUT 'but they do not fit my phone's menu.

I do not have the ability to turn on the hotspot. the menu is not there.

If I can not get it to work, there is no reason to keep it.

Does anyone have a solution. it is as if something is missing in my versions. ??

Answer (score 2):

Yes. With OTA6 (avaible next week) you can. It's a new feature.

Comment: FYI, on Ask Ubuntu/Stack Exchange in general it's considered a bit strange to sign your posts. People can very easily just look over and see your username. Just a friendly tip ;)